# what do i use instead of findViewById in onCreateView using fragment

Tags: findviewbyid

I'm new to Android developing and of course on Fragments.

i have the code below and i want to use findViewById in fragment but because it's on onCreateView it has error

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);

        x2=(Button)getView().findViewById (R.id.btnX2);
        x2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.X2)));
        showResult = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.display);

    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false);
        x2=(Button)v.findViewById (R.id.btnX2);
        x2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.X2)));
        showResult = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.display);
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: thanks very much it worked and now i can run my app but there is a problem , the app runs and i can work with navigation drawer , but there is calculator which i have placed in the fragment which is in the middle of the page but when i tap on a  button on calculator i get the stoped working error (the calculator works wihtout the navigation drawer) , can you give me email that i send you the project and take a look at it please i have worked on it alot but i don't know what else to do

Comment: If this answer is the solution for your question please accept it so that it might help others as well. If you need my further assistance personally you may contact samdodotest@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will be help you

```
 View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
    x2=(Button)view.findViewById (R.id.btnX2);
    x2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.X2)));
    showResult = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.display);
    return view;
```